Show that Boolean ring is Armendariz
Boolean ring : $a^2=a$ for all $a\in R$.
Armendariz ring : A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if whenever $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j=0,\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$.
Boolean rings are commutative but are they Armendariz also?
Why this question is relevant to me : Since I am working on k-potent rings and find relation between these rings and Armendariz rings, so I start from idempotent ring (means Boolean ring) then I further go upto k-potent rings.

Let $a^n=0$, since $a^n=a$, it implies $a=0$. Hence $R$ is reduced and therefore Armendariz.
